# state_tomography_circuits error

Tags: qiskit, state-tomography

I build a QuantumCircuit named qc, I want to generate state
tomography circuits to evaluate fidelity of simulation. I used code,

```
st_qcs = state_tomography_circuits(qc, [qr[1], qr[3], qr[5]])
```

However, I got an error from `state_tomography_circuits`.
I pasted the error message below,

I used IBM quantum. The same codes worked before. But, now `state_tomography_circuits` does not go through. Is this a bug from the function of `state_tomography_circuits`?
I do not know how to fix the issue.

```
  >Cell In[11], line 29 \
st_qcs = state_tomography_circuits(qc, [qr[1], qr[3], qr[5]])

>File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site packages/qiskit/ignis/verification/tomography/basis/circuits.py:\
77 in state_tomography_circuits return _tomography_circuits(circuit, measured_qubits, None,

>  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/ignis/verification/tomography/basis/circuits.py:\
468 in _tomography_circuits
    prep += circuit
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'QuantumCircuit' and 'QuantumCircuit'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to QCSE! This question seems to be Qiskit programming specific and would be a better fit in Stack Overflow or directly with Qiskit (https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues).

Comment: Ignis was deprecated in favor of qiskit-experiments

Answer (score 1):

In Dec 2021, [`qiskit-ignis`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ignis) was [deprecated](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ignis/pull/602) (archived and unmaintained since Jul 2022). It was replaced by [`qiskit-experiments`](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/experiments). With the new package, a new [*Quantum State Tomography* tutorial](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/experiments/manuals/verification/state_tomography.html) is available.

The TL;DR for replacing `state_tomography_circuits` from Ignis with the new [StateTomography](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/experiments/stubs/qiskit_experiments.library.tomography.StateTomography.html) object in your code:

```
st_qcs = StateTomography(qc, measurement_indices=[1, 3, 5])
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try new object of StateTomography.

Comment: How to add error suppression and mitigation in fidelity estimation based on StateTomography? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure. This might be its own question.